# Transferring through US airport. Do I need traveling visa?

Tags: visas, usa, transit

I'm not a resident of USA. But I work on a cruise ship which required me to have C-1/D visa. I am leaving USA and traveling to Mexico but I will have a connecting flight somewhere in another US airport with 1-2 hours waiting for connecting flight to Mexico.

Do I need B1/B2 visa for that? Or my transit visa C-1/D will be enough as long as I am leaving USA?

Comment: Are you traveling to or from your ship, or is this a personal trip?

Comment: @NateEldredge the C-1 visa is valid for a personal trip, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: You mean you'll be in the USA, board a domestic flight from a US airport to another US airport, and then an international flight from that US airport to Mexico? If that's the case, you're already in the US, you don't need any visa for any domestic travel inside the USA on your way out.

Comment: @jcaron you should make that an answer.

Comment: To follow up on jcaron's comment: if you're leaving the US, with a transfer in a US airport on your way to Mexico, you're not going to pass through any passport control until you get to Mexico.  That is, I assume there's some passport control at the port where your ship is.  You will then go to the airport, board your plane, fly to the second airport, and board that plane, all without any immigration control.  The next time you see a passport inspector will be in Mexico.

Answer (score 12):

You have a [C1/D transit/crewmember visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/crewmember.html) from the US, and want to know if you can transit the US en route to a third country.

The answer is **yes**.

This visa has *two* types of permitted usage:

- C1 visas can be used to transit the United States en route to a third country, or en route to or from a ship arriving to or departing the United States. Anyone can have a C1 visa.
- D visas can be used to transit the United States when working on a ship that arrives and departs from the United States, as a crewmember of that ship.

Since your visa is a combined C1/D visa, you can transit the US en route to a third country. You are allowed to exit the airport, change planes, get a hotel, or even cross the country on horseback, provided you leave the US within the time stamped on your passport (typically 29 days).