# Is a C-1 visa required (in addition to a D visa) for a VWP national travelling to the US to join a vessel he/she works on?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, cabin-crew

If I've understood it correctly, a VWP national working as a crewmember on an aircraft needs a D visa if entering the US as a crewmember, or a C1/D visa if **not** entering as a crewmember but exiting as one.

From the [Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/crewmember.html#vessel):

> If you travel to the United States to meet and board the vessel you will work on, you need a transit (C-1) visa.

Does the requirement to also hold a C-1 visa if not entering the US as a crewmember also apply to VWP nationals, who don't normally Need a C visa?

Comment: Did you see https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/crewmember.html?  Was there something there you didn't understand?  Generally the VWP covers purposes of travel allowed under B-1 or B-2 status, which explains why the VWP isn't adequate for crewmembers.

Comment: @pnuts This does not concern me. Nevertheless, it's Norwegian

Comment: This is kind of an edge case of little interest outside the travel industry, but my (possibly flawed) understanding is that D status covers working on a vessel that transits the US, that is, leaving and departing while working on a vessel, and C1 status covers joining or departing a vessel in the US, i.e. working only in one direction of travel.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76968/3221

Comment: @MichaelHampton Doesn't answer my question. I completely overhauled it

Comment: Yes, that's rather different. I suspect not, but in practice everyone who might find themselves in this situation is going to get a C1/D visa anyway.